# How to apply strict data type check on Spark Dataframe/Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to enable strict data type check on spark dataframe/dataset?
We are receiving many system generated and manual feeds from upstream system for our transformation.
    Ask is to extract feeds and perform strict data type checking against schema before starting transformation
    Can someone suggest how efficiently we can do with Spark 2.0?
    We tried following

```
 1. User infereSchema = true, while reading file and get generated dataframes schema to validate against expected schema. Normally infereSchema= true is two phase operation, prove costly for give file
 2. Enforcing schema while creating data frame from csv file


val df:DataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")
     .schema(readSchemaFromAvroSchemaFile)
     .option("header","true")
     .option("inferSchema","false")
     .csv("CSVFileUri")


strict data type check not imposed while writing, 
it applied only while reading dataframe
Is it possible to validate without making read call as it could be expensive operation?
Also in case of double type show some strange behavior 
if we have avro schema 


{
  "namespace":"com.test.schema.validation",
  "name" : "example",
  "type" : "record",
  "fields" [
    {"name":"item_id","type":["null","string"],"default":null},
    {"name":"item_price","type":["null","double"],"default":null}
   ] 
}

CSV file

item_id|item_price
    1|234.90 
    2|634.90
    3|534.90
    4|233A40.90
    5|233E12

df.show(10)- gives me following

    item_id|item_price
    1|234.90 
    2|634.90
    3|534.90
    4|233.90 
    5|2.3E13

Value is Row#4 truncated without any failure so it's hard catch
Please suggest if you have any efficient way to validate schema
Have you come across double type value truncation?
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using scala and hence my suggestion would to use Case classes to define your schema.You can do something like:

```
case class Item(item_price: Long, item_id: Long)

val item = spark.
  read.
  schema(schema).
  csv("path").
  as[Item]
```

Let me know your views about it.

Suggest reading this article from [Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html).

Comment: Thanks @Akhilanand I am working applying schema as case class